# Can you create an 'if' statement for iFrame blocking instead of: X-Frame-Options?

Tags: php, iframe

When you use the following code, at the top of your PHP file, to block visiting from iframes, is it possible to display another php page in its stead, sort of like, change the code to an 'if' statement? If so, how would you do that?

Code:

```
<?php

/* Prevents page from being loaded in an iframe, on another domain, besides its original domain [BEGIN] */

header('X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN'); 

/* Prevents page from being loaded in an iframe, on another domain, besides its original domain [END] */

?>
```

Comment: Since frames are entirely client-side there's no way for PHP to know whether the page is being loaded inside an iframe or not ... so not really.

Comment: Oh, ok. Was still worth making sure.